# MVC2 - How put common LOGIC control (Like Search/Find) on each page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, renderpartial, renderaction

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the following:

On every page (or every page I so desire), I'd like to put a common control widget (e.g. think - Search functionality that contains a textbox+button). What's the best way to do this, and who handles the submit button (assuming it is a submit button)?

i.e. what does my ViewUserControl look like? Does it have a form? does it use jQuery onclick""? Does it post to the main View's action method, or can I redirect it to another Controller/Action?

I have tried using RenderAction of a "Search.ascx" which contains a Form, and is handled by my SearchController... but in the SearchController, it then tries to call RedirectToAction... and I get a complaint about RedirectActions not allowed on Child Actions.

I'm a bit lost on what to do next, so suggestions greatly welcome!
Ray

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the right track (using `ViewUserControl` and `RenderPartial`). But with the information you have provided, it is not easy to see what you other problems are (RenderAction , ...)

It is easy:

- Create a UserControl (.ascx) and get a form in there with URL being /search/..., something that you can get back.
- In your views, call RenderPartial and provided the view name
- Create your controller to receive the post from your search. This is not the same controller as your parent view controller.

Comment: Being nit-picky I would rephrase "This is not the same controller.." to be "This is not necessarily the same controller..." since Search could be an action on the controller that Ray is working on. [Odds are good that a Search controller is appropriate though...]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have the HTML elements show up is to put them in a master page, or in a partial that is referenced by your master page.  I would have it be it's own form and submit to your SearchController.

Let me know if you want more particulars.

Answer (score 0):

RenderPartial is the way to go here. Your control.ascx will consist of it's form and submit button.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to do this

Probably a partial view.  An .ascx file.

> and who handles the submit button
>   (assuming it is a submit button)?

The partial view

> what does my ViewUserControl look
>   like? Does it have a form?

Yes, it has a form.  It should be as self contained as possible.

> does it use jQuery onclick""? Does it
>   post to the main View's action method,
>   or can I redirect it to another
>   Controller/Action?

Well, whatever fits your exact scenario best.  It should probably post to whichever action is most appropriate.  That is not likely to be the main view's action, since the partial is reused in different parent views.

> I have tried using RenderAction of a
>   "Search.ascx" which contains a Form,
>   and is handled by my
>   SearchController... but in the
>   SearchController, it then tries to
>   call RedirectToAction... and I get a
>   complaint about RedirectActions not
>   allowed on Child Actions.

You'll probably want to render it using RenderPartial in the parent view:

```
<%: Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView.ascx") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what my problem was. The replies above are correct. I have my own Search.ascx user control and SearchController, I also used RenderPartial, but what stumped me was that I forgot to explicitly specify the controller/action... so then I was fiddling around with onclick events and Url.Action on my button instead.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("MySearchAction", "MySearchController")) { %>
```

Thanks to all who replied.